# \lesscong extending amssymb

Tags: symbols, stacking-symbols, relation-symbols, amssymb

The amssymb package has `\lesssim` and `\lessapprox` and `\leqq`. Is there a way to construct `\lesscong`?

I looked at the amssymb.sty file, and there's not an obvious way to modify the `\DeclareMathSymbol` which defines the initial three.

I'm familiar with rough commands to stack symbols on top of one another, but I'm interested in the aesthetics of `\lesscong` to "fit" among the initial three. I'm also interested in the slashed and mirrored variants of `\lesscong`, but I'm sure I can create those once I have the "parent" construction for `lesscong`.

Barely related: A long time ago I wanted to create `\appprox` which is three `\sim` symbols stacked on top of one another in such a way that the spacing between consecutive two `\sim` is exactly the same as the spacing in `\approx`. I forgot how I managed to define it, but it may help.

```
\newcommand{\appprox}{\mathrel{\vcenter{\offinterlineskip\hbox{$\m@th\approx$}\vskip-2.50134pt\hbox{$\m@th\approx$}}}}
```

Of course, if I manage to find a nice solution on my own, then I'll post it here for others as well.

Comment: `\DeclareMathSymbol` is useful only if the image of the desired symbol already exists in a font.  The symbols in the `amsfonts` collection (for which `amssymb` merely assigns names) were originally created with Metafont and the fonts in which they were placed later converted to Type 1.  There's no room left in these fonts for additional symbols.  However, the STIX fonts are conceptually open-ended, and a request might be made if you find that possibility interesting.

Comment: @barbarabeeton After a quick read through <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STIX_Fonts_project> it seems that STIX works well with Times New Roman which I can only deduce that it does not work well with Latin Modern which currently is my preference due to my background in mathematics. I'm very much an amateur with fonts so correct me if I'm wrong; If I'm wrong then I will look into STIX in more depth.

Comment: Yes, the STIX fonts are designed to go with Times.  Preference for a particular font style is distinctly personal, so you probably won't be satisfied by STIX if you're particularly fond of Latin Modern, even though the symbol complement of STIX is much more comprehensive.  (You might be interested to learn, though, that Times was for a large part of the 20th century preferentially used by many math publishers before TeX appeared on the scene.)

Comment: Is `\lsime` or `\simlE` an adequate substitute? They're in `unicode-math` and I believe `stix` and `stix2`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done with some `\raisebox`es. The resulting symbol fits well with `\lesssim`, `\lessapprox` and `\leqq`, but it is a bit tall.

What do you think?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newlength{\congwidth}
\newlength{\congheight}
\settowidth{\congwidth}{$\cong$}
\settoheight{\congheight}{$\cong$}
\newcommand{\lesscong}{%
    \mathrel{\smash{%
        \raisebox{-.5\congheight}{$\cong$}%
        \hspace*{-\congwidth}%
        \raisebox{.6\congheight}{$<$}%
    }}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
    \verb|\lesssim|     & \( A \lesssim B \) \\
    \verb|\lessapprox|  & \( A \lessapprox B \) \\
    \verb|\leqq|        & \( A \leqq B \) \\
    \verb|\lesscong|    & \( A \lesscong B \) \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I like that I can also generalize this to make `\lesssimeq`. I plan to use `\lesscong` as a relation asserting the existence of a split monomorphism (from category theory) and `\lesssimeq` for monomorphism instead.

Comment: @AlbertoTakase -- `\lesssimeq` already exists in Unicode (2A8D), and is thus present in the STIX font.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a generic command for defining such symbols. The internal macro `\gl@over` takes an optional argument (for a bit of vertical spacing, default 1pt), the < or > symbol and the symbol to go below.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\lesscong}{\mathrel{\gl@over{<}{\cong}}}
\newcommand{\lesssimeq}{\mathrel{\gl@over{<}{\simeq}}}
\newcommand{\gtrcong}{\mathrel{\gl@over{>}{\cong}}}
\newcommand{\gtrsimeq}{\mathrel{\gl@over{>}{\simeq}}}
\newcommand{\gl@over}[3][1pt]{%
  \vcenter{\m@th\offinterlineskip\ialign{%
    \hfil$##$\hfil\cr #2\cr \noalign{\vskip#1} #3\cr
  }}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
\verb|\lesssim|    & \( A \lesssim B \) \\
\verb|\lessapprox| & \( A \lessapprox B \) \\
\verb|\leqq|       & \( A \leqq B \) \\
\verb|\lesscong|   & \( A \lesscong B \) \\
\verb|\lesssimeq|  & \( A \lesssimeq B \) \\
\verb|\gtrsim|    & \( A \gtrsim B \) \\
\verb|\gtrapprox| & \( A \gtrapprox B \) \\
\verb|\geqq|       & \( A \geqq B \) \\
\verb|\gtrcong|   & \( A \gtrcong B \) \\
\verb|\gtrsimeq|  & \( A \gtrsimeq B \) \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The calculations are left to TeX.

[image]

Comment: I like that your solution uses more primitive TEX commands!